# Unwanted dialog when clicking link to download file

Tags: 12.04, firefox, downloads, dialog

Every time when I click some links (which opens another document), there comes a dialog (see the screen-shot) and I then have to close it manually.

This is really unnecessary, unwanted and irritating (for my mindset).

Are there any way to prevent this dialog from popping up?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Firefox.

[image]

Comment: What dialog? I think that's a Download window. And what type of link did you click so the dialog(?) opened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not really a dialog box expecting an answer from you but Firefox's downloads window, which is shown by default when downloading a file. However, you can switch it off in Firefox's preferences (untick the checkbox "Show downloads windows when downloading a file"). You can find Firefox's preferences under Edit->Preferences in the menu. See the screenshot below.
[image: Firefox Preferences screenshot]

Comment: You can use "Download Status Bar" add-on on Firefox and use it in Mini mode. This will prevent download windows from popping up and you will get download notifications at the left hand corner.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to open docx documents in Firefox, which won't work. Therefore Firefox only has the option of downloading the file for you. Going to edit -> preferences will let you untick the "Show the Downloads window when downloading a file" therefore not showing that window anymore.